# Asking the Managing Editor for Manuscript Update

Tags: publications, peer-review

I submitted the 3rd and final revision of my manuscript last 3 weeks ago, however, it is not yet sent for review. I know that sometimes manuscripts take time to be reviewed but this one is quite strange for me. For the past 2 revisions, the paper was immediately sent for review. The last submission (R2) was only reviewed by the Associate Editor and has a very minor comment. I am hesitant to ask the Managing Editor about the progress of my manuscript. How long should I wait before I could email and ask the Managing Editor? Any advice.

Comment: It is possible, of course, that it won't be reviewed again. I suspect if things happen quickly with this journal it would be fine to ask for a status update any time now.

Comment: @Buffy with other experience from other journal publishers, usually in the last revision (accepted with very minor revisions) they would notify within a week. I will contact the ME asap.

Answer (score 2):

3 weeks is sufficiently long to ask for an update, especially if precedent indicates the manuscript is sent for review "immediately".

I can't tell from your description who to approach, but presumably either the managing editor or the associate editor would be OK.

Comment: another strange thing is that the paper was already accepted and the associate editor has some minor comments and no reviews anymore from reviewers. Based on previous experience from other publishers, when this is the case, it is usually not needed to be sent to reviewers anymore instead the editor will make the final say. But my author's dashboard still indicated "Awaiting fore reviewer assignment" suggesting the journal is looking for another reviewer. is this usual or what?